# How does swift handle nil values in memory

Tags: ios, swift

I know that ARC uses reference counting with compiler inserted increment and decrement operations when (strong) references are being set.  It clears out the memory after the object's last reference group goes out of scope.

My question contains around having a var:

`var key = NSData?`

This by default is nil if no value present.  Now after I assign it and than reassign the value to nil - `key = NSData()`.  Will this remove that data from memory that was previously there?

Any helpful articles would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking if the `NSData` instance will be leaked after overwriting `key` with `nil`?

Comment: @AMomchilov Yes and if assigning it to nil will reset the bytes.  Or do I need to loop through a buffer?

Comment: The whole point of ARC is to free memory on heap in cases like this. However, most likely the memory will *not* be zeroed out. The memory will just be designated "free" to be overwritten when necessary.

Comment: You can test this with the memory viewer in XCode. Make a long `String` that'll be easy to recognize, overwrite the reference with `nil`, and see what happens in the memory view of the debugger

Comment: @AMomchilov What if I want to manually clear out `NSData` from memory?

Comment: That's a good, concrete question. I think it warrants its own new post

Comment: Check this out: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44121

Comment: @AMomchilov does `key = NSData` and `key.setData(NSData)` do the same thing?

Comment: First, I presume you meant `NSData()` in both cases. No, the first is an assignment of a reference to a new `NSData` object to the variable `key`, whereas the second calls a method `setData` on the object `key` is referring to, whose type I don't know.

Comment: Ah, okay.  So in essence, if you assign `nil` to a `var`, you are simply re referencing rather than the `NSData` value that was there, getting overwritten?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you write

```
var key = NSData?
```

The `key` variable is created into the Stack and a `nil` value is assigned to it.

Let's say next you assign an object to key so

```
key = NSData()
```

Now an object of type `NSData` is created into the Heap. And the address of that object is written into the `key` variable (into the Stack).
ARC also takes note that now the `refereneCount` of the NSData object is 1 because it is referenced by 1 variable.

Now we assign again `nil` to key

```
key = nil
```

then ARC detects that the `NSData` living into the Heap is no longer referenced.
So its `referenceCount` drops to 0 and ARC removes it from memory (or probably marks that region of the Heap as free memory that can be used again).

### When exactly is the object deallocated?

As *@AaronBrager* pointed out, the object is not instantly deallocated from memory. It is actually deallocated when the autorelease pool is drained.

The following example does show it

[image]

As you can see the `"end"` print does happen **before** the `Person` object is deallocated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does this happen instantly?

Comment: Yes. ARC (unlike Garbage Collectors) is __deterministic__ so if we write `key = nil`, the `NSData` objects if freed before the next line is executed.

Comment: @appzYourLife I don't think that's true. The object is deallocated at the end of the current run loop when the autorelease pool is drained.

Comment: @AaronBrager: really? I could be wrong. Let me check.

Comment: Is there an documentation for the time of execution on ARC?

Comment: @AaronBrager: You are right. I am updating my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @AaronBrager results are different if define variable var reference1: Person? = Person(name: "John Appleseed") instead of                      
    var reference1: Person?
    reference1 = Person(name: "John Appleseed")