# Variable reassignment causes "Message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: swift, macos

I had code similar to this which was causing the error "-[NSWindow release]: message sent to deallocated instance":

```
    var w = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(100, 100, 500, 500), styleMask: .closable, backing: NSWindow.BackingStoreType.buffered, defer: false)
    w.title = "Window"
    w.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    //w.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
    w.close()

    w = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(100, 100, 500, 500), styleMask: .closable, backing: NSWindow.BackingStoreType.buffered, defer: false)
```

When I added the commented line it worked fine.

I just wanted to know if this is expected behaviour with the way Swift does memory management?
It was quite unexpected that the variable reassignment could be causing this problem.

Comment: This is intriguing, but why is `w` a variable?

Comment: See [How does swift handle nil values in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753328/how-does-swift-handle-nil-values-in-memory).